# «Не» с прилагательным при наречии «совсем»

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно, прилагательные

> Совсем неудачное выступление испортило все мое впечатление о
> театральном искусстве. (выступление очень плохое)
>
> Совсем не удачное выступление не испортило мое впечатление о
> театральном искусстве. (хоть и выступление не провалилось, но и успеха оно не получило)

Возможны ли разные написания прилагательных с частицей ***не***? Удачно ли подобраны объяснения для выбора слитного или раздельного написания с ***не***?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146262/discussion-on-question-by-bodakh------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @МаркИз Не трогайте важные комментарии, которые касаются вопроса. Вы ничего не пишете, а чужое (что иногда даётся трудом) удаляете.

Comment: @МаркИз Поддерживаю нетроганье.

Comment: @МаркИз Другое дело, если комментарии касаются чего-то левого.

Comment: @oleedd если более 20 комментариев касается вопроса, то его лучше дополнить, а не множить комментарии

Comment: @МаркИз Комментарии диалоговые, они не просто множатся. Лингвистика — это такая область, что без обсуждения никак. Здесь надо сделать исключение. А на ветках по другим областям реально комментарии касаются левого, поэтому в чат убирают.

Comment: @oleed вопросы касающиеся модерации можно задать в разделе Мета https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @МаркИз А зачем мне вопросы? Здесь надо поменять подход: 1) Читать комментарии, а не тупо их удалять (не уверен, что их всегда читают). 2) Если есть комментарии, имеющие ценность (касающиеся вопроса/ответа), и дискуссия идёт в правильном русле (не обсуждается вообще левое), то не удалять. В других областях (на других ветках) обсуждения не требуются и длинные дискуссии, как правило, не касаются темы, поэтому любят в чат перемещать, а здесь совсем иначе.

Comment: @МаркИз Особенно не надо удалять комментарии, которые показывают, что ответ не верный. Они очень важны. А то большинство людей (в частности, пришедшие из поисковика) будут верить и ошибаться, используя такое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В принципе возможны оба сочетания с разным смыслом: ***совсем неудачный*** и ***совсем не удачный***, но двойной вариант текста подобрать трудно.

Естественными кажутся, например, такие предложения:

*Актеры в этот день играли довольно посредственно, мое же выступление было **совсем неудачным** (совершенно, крайне).*

***Совсем не удачное** мое выступление не уменьшило моего интереса к театру (далеко не, отнюдь не).*

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

7. При использовании в качестве пояснительного слова наречия ***совсем*** возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательными, что связано с разными значениями, в которых употребляется слово совсем. Ср.: ***совсем ненужная*** встреча (‘совершенно ненужная, лишняя’) — ***совсем не случайная*** встреча (‘отнюдь не случайная’).

В некоторых случаях возможны **два толкования** и, как следствие, допустимы два написания: ***совсем небольшие*** достижения (‘маленькие, скромные’) — ***совсем не*** большие достижения (‘отнюдь не большие’).

Comment: Разве это верно? *Отнюдь/далеко не удачное мое выступление не уменьшило моего интереса к театру.* Надо что-то типа: *Это выступление совсем не удачное, оно провальное.* Как отметил Розенталь, текст должен быть полемическим (мой вариант), а не информативным (у вас). И ещё говорится, что в некоторых случаях возможны два, то есть не всегда. Здесь раздельное так себе. Василий молодец, что заменил на "вовсе", а то не звучит.

Comment: А это вы Василию напишите... Когда вы только научитесь писать правильные комментарии (уточняющие мой ответ или предлагающе его улучшение).

Comment: Предлагаю вам исправить и улучшить ваш пример, а то он неверный.

Comment: Дайте свой верный ответ с правильными примерами, тоже своими  ... и дальше по кругу.

Comment: Мой верный пример выше. Предлагаю вам исправить, чтобы было что-то подобное (чтобы "отнюдь" было уместно).

Comment: А я вам предлагаю от меня отстать, или придется обратиться в  комиссию по правам человека :)

Comment: Ну почему вам плевать на то, что что-то неверно? Там же "отнюдь" вообще не подходит.

Comment: Потому что потому...

Comment: Этот ответ абсолютно неправильный. При слитном написании ‟совсем” заменяется ‟абсолютно”, а при раздельном ‟совсем” заменяется ‟вовсе”, ‟отнюдь”. Этот ответ ужасен. Кто эти люди, которые поставили плюсы, я бы хотел услышать их мнение, почему они это сделали. Этот ответ войдёт в топ 10 ответов по соотношению высокой оценки и его высокой плохости.

Comment: @
Rumpelstiltskin Пожалуйста,  соблюдайте ПРАВИЛА. В комментариях можно уточнить ответ или  предложить его улучшение. Для критики используйте поле ответа.

Comment: Как и написал oleed: ‟Разве это верно? Отнюдь/далеко не удачное мое выступление не уменьшило моего интереса к театру”. ‟Далеко” здесь не очень подходит. Лучше так: ‟Отнюдь/вовсе не удачное мое выступление не уменьшило моего интереса к театру”. Разве это верно? При раздельном написании даже его смысл трудно понять.

Comment: @ Rumpelstiltskin Извините,  пожалуйста, у меня мало свободного времени, поэтому не будет возможности отвечать на комментарии, особенно по старым темам. Обсудите их с другими участниками. Я вообще не планирую в ближайшее время часто бывать на форуме.

Comment: Мало свободного времени, но только что вы сидели и сочиняли максимально сомнительный, неотчётливый, наполненный на ходу придуманными фантазиями ответ про тире.

Comment: @ Rumpelstiltskin Это я давно уже сочинила, еще до вашего ответа :) Просто тогда не стала печатать, хотелось других послушать. А все "фантазии" сверены по вузовскому учебнику. Я разве сама такое придумаю :) Да и озвучивать здесь что-то свое надо очень осмотрительно, Я стараюсь это не делать или указываю, что это мое мнение.

Comment: Ну хорошо, что хоть признались.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin В чем "хоть призналась"? Я полагаю, что разумнее в данном случае использовать информацию от лингвиста-специалиста по синтаксису. А ссылку на эту книгу я уже устала давать, к тому же издание у меня другого года, а не то, что в Сети.

Answer (score 1):

Прилагательные с частицей не пишутся раздельно, если есть противопоставление.
Первый пример неудачный с точки зрения стилистики и семантики. Предложение не полное, так как не указано, чьё выступление. Насколько взбалмошным должен быть зритель, чтобы одна плохая постановка испортила впечатление обо всём театральном искусстве. Я бы предложил такие варианты:

1. *Очень неудачное выступление актеров испортило мое впечатление о пьесе / об этой труппе.*
2. *Моё совсем неудачное выступление испортило мне всё впечатление о театральном искусстве.*

Второй пример тоже неверный. Прежде всего нет противопоставления. А когда появляются новые слова, надо убирать те слова, которые не несут дидактической нагрузки. Получается примерно так:
*Вовсе не удачное выступление труппы, а роскошный буфет поднял моё настроение.*

Answer (score 0):

Слово ‟противопоставление” очень плохо подходит для описания отрицания, вообще непонятно, почему лингвисты выбрали это слово, а потом использовали (у меня есть предположения, конечно). Больше подходит слово ‟противоречие”. Отрицание предполагает противоречие некому утверждению, которое высказывается в контексте или подразумевается. В обоих этих предложениях нет противоречий каким-либо утверждениям в контекстах, поэтому здесь нет отрицания.

> Совсем не удачное выступление испортило все моё впечатление о театральном искусстве. (При раздельном написании предложение бессмысленное, потому что удачное выступление не может испортить впечатление о театральном искусстве. Это и так очевидно, что если что-то и испортило впечатление, то это было не удачное выступление.)
>
> Совсем не удачное выступление не испортило моё впечатление о театральном искусстве. (При раздельном написании предложение бессмысленное.)

В обоих предложениях будет слитное написание.

Отрицание будет в таком предложении:

> При чтении его биографии непонятно, почему при таких удачных выступлениях он так стремился переехать в другой город. Это объясняют другие источники, которые утверждают, что его выступления в тот период были совсем не удачные.